# Jquery - JSON.stringify, array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

i hope somebody can help me, the array value is empty in the post.

```
$(function start() {

    c_all = new Array('#div { font-color:#ff0000; border:1px solid #00ff00; }', '#div_2 { font-color:#ff0000; }', '.line2 { font-color:#00ffff; }');

    css(c_all);

});


function css(x) {

    values = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        c0_selector = '' + x[i].match(/^.*{/) + '';
        c0_selector = c0_selector.replace(/\s*/g, '');
        c0_selector = c0_selector.replace(/{/, '');

        x[i] = x[i].replace(/^.*{/, '');
        x[i] = x[i].replace(/}/, '');

        c0_arr = x[i].split(';');

        values['' + c0_selector + ''] = new Array();

        $('#log').append(''+c0_selector+'<br />');

        for (i2 = 0; i2 < c0_arr.length; i2++)
        {
            values[''+c0_selector+''][i2] = c0_arr[i2].split(':');
            $('#log').append(''+c0_arr[i2]+'<br />');  
        }

    }

    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(values),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
    });


}
```

working example -> http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/448/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try making `values` an Object, (like it should be in javascript for named keys).

```
var values = {};
```

Also, it is a *really* good idea to declare your variables with the `var` keyword, so you're not creating global variables.

Also, no need for `'' + c0_selector + ''` since you already have a String. Just do `c0_selector`.

Finished product logs the populated Object. http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/450/

Answer (score 9):

This is straight from the ECMAScript spec.

> The abstract operation JA(value)
>   serializes an array. It has access to
>   the stack, indent, gap, and space of
>   the invocation of the stringify
>   method. The representation of arrays
>   includes only the elements between
>   zero and array.length – 1 inclusive.
>   Named properties are excluded from the
>   stringification. An array is
>   stringified as an open left bracket,
>   elements separated by comma, and a
>   closing right bracket.

Basically any named properties are excluded from the result.