# json.stringify returns blank [ ] for one object and not a filled { }

Tags: javascript, json

I have looked at this post:
[Jquery - JSON.stringify, array is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602713/jquery-json-stringify-array-is-empty)
and also checked around with other forums and have searched google and have not found a decent answer to this.

Basically, when I use json.stringify on me saved[] array, it's creating the json string correctly on everything but one array value, which would be at saved[2]. Just for an example here is how the stringify posts both 1 and 2 in the array:

```
"1":{"doodleID":"716","tid":"26","outline":"sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24solid.swf","skin":"sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24face.swf","hair":"sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24hair.swf","misc":"sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24lips.swf","addlayer1":"","addlayer2":"","addlayer3":"","doodlename":"Mom","headsize":"95","flip":"true","skincolor":"E8B18C","skinblush":"sites/default/files/skin_color/e8b18c.swf","haircolor":"855D33","mouth":"sites/default/files/mouth/lips_color_d6570a_1.swf","neck":"sites/default/files/neck/pearl_necklace_solid.swf","neck_optlayer":"sites/default/files/neck/pearl_necklace_color.swf","neck_optcolor":"f8e5be"},
"2":[]
```

It writes out one correctly but when it comes to 2 the values aren't being correctly parsed into a json string. So you know what the saved array looks like at both 1 and 2 value, here (the array is larger, I just think this should be all you need to see what's going wrong. If not, let me know. It works perfect with 1, and not 2) :

```
  '1' ...
    'doodleID' => "716"
    'tid' => "26"
    'outline' => "sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24solid.swf"
    'skin' => "sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24face.swf"
    'hair' => "sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24hair.swf"
    'misc' => "sites/default/files/doodlekin/female24lips.swf"
    'addlayer1' => ""
    'addlayer2' => ""
    'addlayer3' => ""
    'doodlename' => "Mom"
    'headsize' => "95"
    'flip' => "true"
    'skincolor' => "E8B18C"
    'skinblush' => "sites/default/files/skin_color/e8b18c.swf"
    'haircolor' => "855D33"
    'mouth' => "sites/default/files/mouth/lips_color_d6570a_1.swf"
    'neck' => "sites/default/files/neck/pearl_necklace_solid.swf"
    'neck_optlayer' => "sites/default/files/neck/pearl_necklace_color.swf"
    'neck_optcolor' => "f8e5be"
'2' ...
    'doodleID' => "291"
    'tid' => "27"
    'outline' => "sites/default/files/doodlekin/male66solid.swf"
    'skin' => "sites/default/files/doodlekin/male66face.swf"
    'hair' => "sites/default/files/doodlekin/male66hair.swf"
    'misc' => ""
    'addlayer1' => ""
    'addlayer2' => ""
    'addlayer3' => ""
    'doodlename' => "John"
    'headsize' => "95"
    'skincolor' => "EEBF7C"
    'skinblush' => "sites/default/files/skin_color/eebf7c.swf"
    'haircolor' => "353535"
    'eyes' => ""
    'eyes_shadow' => ""
    'eyes_optlayer' => ""
    'eyes_optcolor' => ""
    'mouth' => "sites/default/files/mouth/goatee_solid.swf"
    'mouth_optlayer' => "sites/default/files/mouth/goatee_color.swf"
    'mouth_optcolor' => "646464"
```

My question is why is saved[2] being removed from saved when I use: 
postData = JSON.stringify( saved );

BUT the saved array still exist when it shows 2. Any help would be great full and if you need more insight I will give it to you. The reason I'm using a global variable is because I'm using about 10 different functions that need to call that variable and I don't want to lose sight of it through the designer.

UPDATE: Just realized this issue only happens with firefox too. I'm running firefox 4 Beta 7. Any chance that could be a reason why json.stringify isn't working correctly? Irt's working with Chrome and IE 8.

UPDATE 2: Code For entire save:

```
function userSavedDoodlekin(flag)
{   
    // For leave page check
    addToCartPage = "true";

    pID = $("#neededInfo .productID").text();
    tID = $("#neededInfo .templateID").text();
    pAttr = new Object();
    tBg = $("#neededInfo .templateBG").text();
    tCoords = $("#neededInfo .templateCoords").text();

    $("#neededInfo .productAttr").each(function(){
        pAttr[$(this).attr('alt')] = $(this).text();
    });

    store_doodlekin("product", pID, "productID");
    store_doodlekin("product", pAttr, "productAttr");
    store_doodlekin("product", tID, "templateID");
    store_doodlekin("product", tBg, "templateBG");
    store_doodlekin("product", tCoords, "templateCoords");

    // Data for post "json" serialized  
    postData = JSON.stringify( saved );
    flag = '';

    // Check for flag
    if(flag == "true")
    {
        flag = '?saved=true'; 
    }

    // Test before launch
    // alert(postData);
    // alert(dump(saved));

    // Save the doodlekin and start another loop for the next one to save if another in line.
    // Data Sent Back: object.status = (1 or 0), object.data = (error message)

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "data="+postData,
        url: "/designer/save",
        success: function(obj){
            if(obj.status == 1){
                // alert(obj.data);
                window.location = "/cart";
            }
            else if(obj.status == 0){
                alert(obj.data);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("textStatus: "+textStatus);
            alert("errorThrown: "+errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: It's probably a typo somewhere, possibly in the data itself. Could you post code where the JSON is created, and displayed? Complete with brackets, braces and semi-colons. The act of writing a working (or failing) minimal problem example often reveals where the problem is.

Comment: Check the updates to the post, only reason I see it not being that, is because now I know it works with Firefox 3.5 + 3.6, and with IE 8, and Chrome. I'm ONLY having the issue in the Firefox on my work PC, Firefox 4 Beta 7. Besides that, when that array gets saved it works completely fine on the rest of the browsers.

Comment: Also, just realized what you were saying about Prototype and no, I usaully stick with jQuery when coding. And that's on version 1.3.2 in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an older version of Prototype? I've had a similar issue where Prototype (or another library) adds incompatible .toJSON methods that break stringify.

Comment: http://www.JSON.org/json2.js
2010-08-25

This is when the last update was made to the current version I'm using. If you check my update, atm it works fine in Chrome and IE, I'm just not sure if it's because I'm using the Firefox 4 Beta 7, or if it's something that the plugin is doing, because it only happens on occasion.